# How to declare std::vector with an 'n' dimensional array?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, multidimensional-array, stdvector

My thoughts are the following:
 for e.g. a two-dimensional array:

```
int a[9][9];
std::vector<int** a> b;
```

But what if I have

```
/* I know, it is usually a bad practise to have more than 2 dimensional arrays, but it can happen, when you need it */
int a[3][4][5][6]; 
std::vector<int**** a> b; // ? this just looks bad
```

Comment: can you use `std::array` instead of a c-style array?

Comment: That's a vector of pointers, not a multi-dimensional array. Either use a vector of vectors (of vectors...), or a flat `vector<int>` using arithmetic for multidimensional indexing.

Comment: @dwcanillas yes, I could use std::array

Comment: @Mike Seymour using arithmetic for multidimensional indexing was downvoted by my superiors, because that would make the code hard to read and maintain. But yes, that would be a good solution.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking for a `vector` that would point to the elements in `a`, or how to copy `a` into a `vector` with similar semantics?

Comment: @Snowman: Wrap the vector in a class, and the arithmetic in an accessor function. Then it can be as easy to read as `a(1,2,3) = 42;`

Comment: @Mike Seymour that's good Idea thanks I will do that - I did that, except for the nice accessor function idea, just I tried to give a generic answer below (deleted that now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use an alias declaration:

```
template <typename T, size_t I, size_t J, size_t K, size_t N>
using SomeArr = std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<T, I>, J>, K>, N>;

int main()
{
    SomeArr<int,3,4,5,6> arr;
    std::vector<SomeArr<int,3,4,5,6>> someVec;
    someVec.push_back(arr);
}
```

Comment: You could generalize your alias quite a bit. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30155608/2069064).

Comment: @Barry nice, thanks.  Still on VS2012 at work so I havent learned all the stuff that comes with 2013/2015

Comment: @Barry why were structs used in that answer? Is it not possible to be done using only alias declarations?

Comment: Can you think of a way to? I'm fairly sure it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
struct MD_array{ //multidimentional array
   a[3][4][5][6];
};
std::vector<MD_array> b;
```

Then you can access each array like so:

```
b[i].a[x][y][z][w] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
int a[3][4][5][6]; 
std::vector<int**** a> b;
```

in two ways like this

```
int a[3][4][5][6]; 
std::vector<int ( * )[4][5][6]> b; 

b.push_back( a );
```

and like this

```
int a[3][4][5][6]; 
std::vector<int ( * )[3][4][5][6]> b; 

b.push_back( &a );
```

Though it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.:)

Comment: What Mike Seymour said in the comments, is what I'd like to achieve :)
I just wanted to know, what is the best practise in this case ( I am student, and want to learn the tricks of the trade ).
I am already implementing it:
"Wrap the vector in a class, and the arithmetic in an accessor function. Then it can be as easy to read as a(1,2,3) = 42"